# Unexpected type with arithmetic operators

Tags: java

not sure why this isn't working. I know this is probably basic and I am pathetic at this but can anyone shed any light?

Code:

```
public class CarLoan {
    int carLoan;
    double interestRate;
    int lengthOfLoan;
    int downPayment;

  public CarLoan(int loanAmount, double intRate, int lol, int dp) {
    loanAmount = carLoan;
    intRate = interestRate;
    lol = lengthOfLoan;
    dp = downPayment;
  }

  public void totalLoan() {
    int totalLoan = (carLoan / interestRate) += carLoan;
    System.out.println("The total amount you have loaned is:" + totalLoan);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CarLoan carL1 = new CarLoan(6500, 12.5, 3, 0);
    carL1.totalLoan();

    }
 }
```

I am getting the error:

```
CarLoan.java:15: error: unexpected type
int totalLoan = (carLoan / interestRate) += carLoan;
^
required: variable
found:    value
1 error
```

I tried a few things to rectify:

1. Reversed the constructor and instance variables
2. Defined the totalLoan method without a creating new variable (example: (carloan / interestRate) += carLoan)
3. Tried introducing a "int" return type to the totalLoan method but I was working with a few varTypes.

Comment: You can only use a variable before the `+=` operator.

Comment: The assignment in your constructor assign the internal variables into the parameters, it should be the other way around.

Comment: The assignments in your constructor are the wrong way around. Instead of assigning the values of the parameters to your fields, you assign the values of your fields (all 0) to your parameters. Since Java is pass-by-value that has no effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break down the problems with the

```
int totalLoan = (carLoan / interestRate) += carLoan;
```

line. First of all, the `+=` operator is adding and assigning to a variable. For example, if you have

```
foo += bar;
```

then the value of `foo + bar` is computed and the result is assigned to `foo` as its new value. However, your code assigns `(carLoan / interestRate)` to `totalLoan`, resulting in the expected **value** that is assigned and then you try to add `carLoan` to this **value** and assign to the **value** rather than the variable. Secondly, you are computing the division of an `int` and a `double`, which leads to data loss if you want to assign it to an int. A possible solution would be:

```
int totalLoan = (int) ((carLoan / interestRate) + carLoan);
```

or even:

```
int totalLoan = (int) ((carLoan * (1 + interestRate)) / interestRate);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, great explanation. Making silly mistakes and getting too ahead of myself.

Comment: @JackM happy to help. Don't worry about making mistakes, those are part of learning.